# Representing the cyclic differentiation pattern of $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(\sin(x))$ using linear algebra.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, representation-theory

It is known that the derivatives of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ follow this pattern:
$$\frac{d^1}{dx^1}(\sin(x))=\cos(x)$$
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(\sin(x))=-\sin(x)$$
$$\frac{d^3}{dx^3}(\sin(x))=-\cos(x)$$
$$\frac{d^4}{dx^4}(\sin(x))=\sin(x)$$
Motivated by the matrix representation of complex numbers. I thought one could interpret this pattern in the context of a coordinate plane and 90-degree rotations ($\sin$ rotates around to cosine, rotates around again to negative $\sin$, and so on for each derrivative). One can assign the following basis vectors for the space:
$$\mathbf{e}_{1}=\sin(x);\quad\mathbf{e}_{2}=\cos(x)$$
Thus a linear combination of a sine and cosine function relates to a vector in the following way:
$$C_1\sin(x)+C_2\cos(x)\equiv\begin{pmatrix} C_1 \\ C_2 \end{pmatrix}$$
The n'th derivative can be interpreted as the following matrix-vector product
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(C_1\sin(x)+C_2\cos(x))\equiv\begin{pmatrix} \cos(\frac{n\pi}{2}) & -\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2}) \\ \sin(\frac{n\pi}{2}) & \cos(\frac{n\pi}{2})\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} C_1 \\ C_2 \end{pmatrix}
$$
So taking a derrivative is equivalent to rotating the vector representing the function by 90 degrees. I believe that the inner product would then be defined as:
$$\langle C_1\sin(x)+C_2\cos(x),C_3\sin(x)+C_4\cos(x)\rangle=C_1C_3+C_2C_4$$
Though this doesn't seem to have an immediately useful interpretation. If you let $(n\in\mathbb{R})$, then (using the sum of angles formula) a possible value for the fractional derivative of $C_1\sin(x)+C_2\cos(x)$ is given by:
$$\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}(C_1\sin(x)+C_2\cos(x))=C_1\sin(x+\frac{n\pi}{2}) + C_2\cos(x+\frac{n\pi}{2}) $$
for $f(x)=C_1\sin(x)$ and $n=\frac{1}{2}$, one obtains:
$$\frac{d^{0.5}}{dx^{0.5}}(C_1\sin(x))=C_1\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4}) $$
Which coincides with the answer given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1593339/how-do-you-take-the-fractional-derivative-j-frac12fx-where-fx-w-sin). Has such a representation of the derivative of $\sin(x)$ been investigated before? What useful applications can be obtained from this interpretation? As a sidenote I am using the equivalence notation loosely so if there is a better way to write it let me know.

Comment: Sounds interesting! What should I imagine by $\frac {d^n}{dx^n}$ for fractional values of $n$ or say $n\in\mathbb R$

Comment: @I_don't_know_maths_ In this context $\frac{d^{\frac{1}{2}}}{dx^{\frac{1}{2}}}(sin(x))$ is roughly asking what function would make sense halfway between a transformation from $sin(x)$ to $cos(x)$ (or $sin(x+\frac{\pi}{2}$). The rotation matrix tells you that it would be the phase shift halfway between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$. I don't think there is a correct answer for what the true fractional derivative is ($sin(x)$ has multiple possible ones as you can see in the linked thread), but this interpretation yields a certain answer.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\pmatrix{\frac{d^nS}{dx^n} \\ \frac {d^nC}{dx^n}} =\pmatrix{0 & -1 \\ 1 & \ 0 }^n\pmatrix{S \\ C }$$

- **How did I come to above formula?**

We can use [the change of basis of vectors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2LTAUO1TdA&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab&index=13)(thanks to [$3$Blue$1$Brown YT channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYO_jab_esuFRV4b17AJtAw))

We know $\frac {d^nS}{dx^n} = S(x + \frac {n\pi}{2})$ and same for $\frac {d^nC}{dx^n} = C(x + \frac {n\pi}{2})$

Here we note the fact that every time we differentiate the result we get is the rotating axis with $90^0$ that is $\hat i \text { lands on } \hat j$
thus the same keeps happening every time we are differentiating.

$\pmatrix {\cos\theta && \sin\theta\\-\sin\theta&&\cos\theta}_{\theta = \frac\pi2} = \pmatrix{0&&-1\\1&&0}$

Thus, for $n$th time we have
$$
\pmatrix{\frac{d^nS}{dx^n} \\ \frac {d^nC}{dx^n}} =\pmatrix{0 & -1 \\ 1 & \ 0 }^n\pmatrix{S \\ C }$$

Comment: You should have taken $\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 &  0 \end{pmatrix}$. With your matrix you are rotating backwards (clockwise instead of direct=anti-clockwise)

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks Jean you are right I'll correct my mistake 

Answer (score 2):

Write
$$
\pmatrix{\cos' \\ \sin'}
=
\pmatrix{0 & -1 \\ 1 & \hphantom{-}0}
\pmatrix{\cos \\ \sin }
$$
Let the matrix above be $J$. Then $J^2=-I$. In fact, $J$ corresponds to $i$ in the [matrix representation of complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Matrix_representation_of_complex_numbers). And you can take $J^t$ for any real number $t$ by considering rotations by $t\pi/2$.